# Polymer, how to wait for core-ajax to finish before rendering other elements?

Tags: polymer

Update: here are the docs for this situation: [Conditional templates use the if attribute to conditionally create a template instance.](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html)

this app, [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/oQv2sPHBirN8FGlcrXTP?p=preview), should do the following:

1. use core-ajax component to get project_location from DB(JSON in this example)
2. use google-map component to display the map with marker
3. when user drags the market, use core-ajax to save the new location to DB

Q: How to make google-map component to wait with it's rendering until AJAX request is finished?

Currently this error is appearing:
"Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: latitude must be a number", and I assume that is because google-map is rendered before {{project_location}} is initiated.

```
     <core-ajax id="ajax_get_location"
        auto
        url="project_location.json"
        params='{"idProject":"{{idProject}}"}'
        on-core-response="{{locationLoaded}}"
        handleAs="json"
        response = "{{project_location}}"></core-ajax>



     <google-map id="project_location_map" 
          zoom="{{project_location.location_map_zoom}}" 
          fitToMarkers>
      <google-map-marker 
                   latitude  ="{{project_location.location_map_marker_latitude | toFixed(2)}}"
                   longitude ="{{project_location.location_map_marker_longitude | toFixed(2)}}"
                   title     ="{{project_title}}" 
                   draggable ="true"
                   >
       {{project_title}}
      </google-map-marker></google-map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest approach is not to think about this as a timing issue with `<core-ajax>`. Fundamentally, the problem is that you don't want to include the `<google-map>` element on your page until there's a value for `project_location`. In your snippet, the `project_location` value comes from `<core-ajax>`, but you could easily imagine a different implementation in which `project_location` is populated via some other means.

So, if you think about it that way, what would make sense is to wrap the `<google-map>` in a conditional template that checks for a value of `project_location`:

```
<template if="{{project_location}}">
  <google-map>
     ...
  </google-map>
<template>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it and found out that whether you use `if` or not didn't influence the result. It just appears **after** you got the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can change a value on the model when core-axax has finished and wrap the other elements with a `<template if="{{ajaxHasFinished}}">...</templ<te>`

Answer (score 0):

Besides what others have said, an another way is demonstrated in the tutorial https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-3.html, in which you create another element to do the ajax thing, and use it in your original element. The data transfer is achieved through attributes and data binding.

I think it's a better way because you separate the data display with data fetching, making it look better in software engineering.

P.S. I've tried what other answers said, but I found out it didn't matter whether you use `if` condition or not.

Comment: 'if' condition in template is must, no matter if you are using core-ajax directly or indirectly trough another element.
Sometimes AJAX response can come quicker then the rendering of other elements, and in that case you won't notice the problem - data will be there for the other elements.
Maybe that has happen in your tests.

Comment: @goceribeski But in my test, I let my backend script to sleep for 2 seconds and didn't use `if` condition, and the template would still wait 2 seconds to appear.