# Polymer: "Attributes on paper-dialog were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types."

Tags: html, polymer

So I get this warning,

> Attributes on paper-dialog were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.

But I'm not sure how to get rid of it. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870541/how-to-resolve-attributes-on-element-name-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgr). My first attempt was to to take the paper-dialog import and move it to the very top of my imports. That didn't rid that error. Next I tried putting the import at the bottom of the list of imports... no luck.

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../font-roboto/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../core-tooltip/core-tooltip.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../core-icons/core-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
</head>
```

My paper dialog is in a custom paper element, which is in a core-drawer... if that helps.

Index.html:

```
 <core-drawer-panel drawerWidth="74px">
        <div drawer id="drawer">
            <navigation-toolbar></navigation-toolbar>
        </div>

        <div main>
           ...
        </div>
```

Inside Navigation-toolbar.html

```
<core-icon-button icon="perm-identity" on-click="{{ toggleSignOutDialog }}" id="signoutButton"></core-icon-button>

...

<paper-dialog heading="Sign Out?" id="signOutDialog" closeSelector="[dismissive]" horizontal justified layout style="width: 40%;" transition="core-transition-center" backdrop autoclosedisabled>
        Are you sure you want to sign out?

        <div horizontal justified layout id="actionButtons" style="margin: 30px 0 0 0;">
            <paper-button dismissive autofocus>Go back</paper-button>

            <paper-button dismissive on-click="{{ doLogOut }}" style="color: #03a9f4;">
                Log out
            </paper-button>
        </div>
    </paper-dialog>
```

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the element import; It has to do with how you use the element, show that code.

Comment: Gotcha, I added some more details.

Comment: I can't see where the problem may be; But generally this error is happening when you include an element on your page before there are values for it's attributes. 

Here is one solved example how to avoid that using conditional template: [how-to-wait-for-core-ajax-to-finish-before-rendering-other-elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093684/polymer-how-to-wait-for-core-ajax-to-finish-before-rendering-other-elements)

Comment: I see... I'm keep playing with it. I'm also using gulp and vulcanize. Could those possibly be the culprit?

Comment: I should also say that this one warning is the result of Refactoring for CSP in the Chrome Dev Editor. Before Refactoring I had approx. 50 of these lovely warnings for a whole mess of different polymer elements. Could that be something?