# Execute method after all json files are loaded using Polymer's core-ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, polymer, web-component

I need to execute method `callMe()` after all json files will be loaded.
I am using Polymer's core-ajax to load json files. 
My code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-schedule" attributes="speakersUrl sessionsUrl scheduleUrl">
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{scheduleUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{scheduleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{sessionsUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{sessionsResponse}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{speakersUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{speakersResponse}}"></core-ajax>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    (function() {
        Polymer('my-schedule', {
            speakersUrl: '../../data/speakers.json',
            sessionsUrl: '../../data/sessions.json',
            scheduleUrl: '../../data/schedule.json',
            speakersResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.speakers = response.response;
            },
            sessionsResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.sessions = response.response;
            },
            scheduleResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.schedule = response.response;
            },
            callMe: function() {
                console.log('I was called after all json files loaded');
            }
        });
    })();
    </script>
```

Who can help me with that?
**Note:** No jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. By using `observe` you can check the values each time they change and wait for all three to be present. You can also bind directly to the `response` attribute of `core-ajax` instead of having to do a setter.

```
<polymer-element name="my-schedule" attributes="speakersUrl sessionsUrl scheduleUrl">
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{scheduleUrl}}" handleAs="json" response="{{speakers}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{sessionsUrl}}" handleAs="json" response="{{sessions}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{speakersUrl}}" handleAs="json" response="{{schedule}}"></core-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
    (function() {
        Polymer('my-schedule', {
            speakersUrl: '../../data/speakers.json',
            sessionsUrl: '../../data/sessions.json',
            scheduleUrl: '../../data/schedule.json',
            observe: {
              'speakers schedule sessions': 'checkReady'  
            },
            checkReady: function() {
              if (this.sessions && this.speakers && this.schedule) { this.callMe(); }
            },
            callMe: function() {
                console.log('I was called after all json files loaded');
            }
        });
    })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Michael Bleigh's approach seems to be cleaner. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. Check when the data is ready -> call custom_element in which callMe() is called in the ready() callback.

   ```
     <my-template if="{{data_json.list}}">
          <my-custom_element
             pass_data ='{{data_json.list}}'
          ></my-custom_element></template>
   ```

Similar: [Polymer, how to wait for core-ajax to finish before rendering other elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093684/polymer-how-to-wait-for-core-ajax-to-finish-before-rendering-other-elements)

2. Another is to callcallMe() in scheduleResponse();

Comment: The second approach will not work because when I will call the method in scheduleResponse() another files can be still downloading.

Answer (score 0):

i think what i would to here is make 3 true / false variables and after each load set the status of the loaded item to true and check status of the others. to keep it from firing more then once you could use 1 more variable to check if method has already run.

example

```
  <polymer-element name="my-schedule" attributes="speakersUrl sessionsUrl scheduleUrl">
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{scheduleUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{scheduleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{sessionsUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{sessionsResponse}}"></core-ajax>
        <core-ajax auto url="{{speakersUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-response="{{speakersResponse}}"></core-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
    (function() {
        Polymer('my-schedule', {
            speakersUrl: '../../data/speakers.json',
            speakerStatus: false,
            sessionsUrl: '../../data/sessions.json',
            sessionStatus: false,
            scheduleUrl: '../../data/schedule.json',
            scheduleStatus: false,
            hasRun: false,
            speakersResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.speakers = response.response;
                this.speakerStatus = true;
                this.checkStatus();
            },
            sessionsResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.sessions = response.response;
                this.sessionStatus = true;
                this.checkStatus();
            },
            scheduleResponse: function(event, response) {
                this.schedule = response.response;
                this.scheduleStatus = true;
                this.checkStatus();
            },
            checkStatus: function () {
              if (this.speakerStatus && this.sessionStatus && this.scheduleStatus && !this.hasRun) {
                this.callMe();
                this.hasRun = true;
              }
            },
            callMe: function() {
                console.log('I was called after all json files loaded');
            }
        });
    })();
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **on-core-complete** event on your core-ajax element to check for when the json has loaded. 
E.G `<core-ajax auto url="{{scheduleUrl}}" handleAs="json" on-core-complete="{{scheduleResponse}}"></core-ajax>`

Read more: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-ajax.html